# how to bind dynamic generated inputs to $scope

Tags: html, angularjs

I am retrieving items from db put them in dir-paginate or ng-repeat what i am trying here to pass id in as model name to get key and name also as key as i am fetching a array to create many inputs and retrieve them in controller, but when i retrieve ng-model object values with console.log($scope.values); it says undefined.
how i will pass multiple generated inputs to controller in scope object is my question even ng-click dont work ??
**view**

```
<form angular-validator-submit="submitForm()"
    name="submit-form" class="form-horizontal" novalidate
    angular-validator>
    <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>S.No</th>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr dir-paginate="x in items| itemsPerPage: pageSize" current-page="currentPage">
        <td><input type="text" name="id" ng-model="values.{{x.id}}[$index]"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="test" ng-model="values.{{x.name}}[$index]"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </form>

        $scope.submitform = function(){
        console.log($scope.values);
    }
```

Comment: Did you try `values[x.id][$index]` instead of `values.{{x.id}}[$index]` ?

Comment: its working like that but in controller $scope.values is undefined

Comment: `ng-model` takes an angular expression as value. I'm pretty sure `values.{{x.id}}[$index]` is not valid (it should even throw a `Syntax Error`, check your web console).

Comment: no its not throwing any error in console as i put $scope in console it give undefined.

Comment: Define/initialize `$scope.values = [];` first in your controller.

Comment: Because the `ng-repeat` uses a pagination filter, the `$index` will not equal the index values of the individual items in the `items` array. The `$index` starts at zero no matter which page is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-model="values[x.id]"` will do the work and define `$scope.values = [];` as suggested in comments.